# Comparar varios patrones con Pattern y Matcher en java

Tags: java, regex

Tengo que leer de un fichero te texto datos línea por línea y, según lo que haya en la línea, aplicarle un patrón distinto para reconocer la información.

Este es una parte del fichero:

```
[018-0001]
type= category
name= Distritos
id= http://datos.madrid.es/egob/kos/actividades/1ciudad21distritos
[018-0002]
type= category
name= Actividades calle, arte urbano
id= http://datos.madrid.es/egob/kos/actividades/ActividadesCalleArteUrbano
[018-0003-0006]
type= category
name= Carreras y maratones
id=http://datos.madrid.es/egob/kos/actividades/ActividadesDeportivas/CarrerasMaratones
```

He creado estos 4 patrones, los cuales funcionan perfectamente:

```
Pattern pCode = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}\\W(\\d{4}|\\d{4}\\W\\d{4})");
Pattern pTypeCategory = Pattern.compile(".*type= category.*");
Pattern pName = Pattern.compile(".*name=\\s(.*)");
Pattern pId = Pattern.compile(".*id=\\s(.*)");

Matcher mCode = null;
Matcher mName = null;
Matcher mTypeCategory = null;
Matcher mId = null;
```

El archivo lo leo como texto:

```
File archivo = new File (sFile);
FileReader fr = null;
try {
    fr = new FileReader (archivo);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Y lo que más quebraderos de cabeza me da es que los datos pueden venir desordenados. No tienen por qué ir en ese orden. Había pensado en hacer un `List` de pattern y recorrerlo con un `for:each` para saber qué patrón es el válido y, en función de eso, saber en qué línea estoy.

Mi pregunta es: yo leo una línea y ¿tengo que comparar los 4 patrones cada vez que leo una nueva línea para ver qué tipo de dato estoy leyendo?

Comment: La información no está relacionado entre sí? Da la impresión que las 4 lineas siempre van juntas y en orden

Comment: Hola @Christian. La respuesta depende de cómo estés leyendo el archivo. ¿Podrías por favor incluir el código de esa parte para ver lo que estás haciendo? Encontrarás en enlace a [edit] al pie de tu pregunta

Comment: Ya edite el post, la informacion puede venir desordenada eso es lo que mas me desconcierta

Answer (score 1):

#### Archivos INI

Estás leyendo un archivo INI.

```
[seccion1]
clave1=valor1
clave2=valor2

[seccion2]
clave1=valor3
clave2=valor4
```

Lo más sencillo, sería utilizar una librería específicamente para eso.

Por ejemplo, con [**ini4j**](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/):

```
//cargar el carchivo como Wini
File archivo = new File(sFile); //sFile es la ruta
Wini ini = new Wini(archivo);

System.out.format("%-15s%-12s%-25s%s%n", "Codigo", "Categoria", "Nombre", "id");

//leer todas las secciones
Collection<Profile.Section> sectionList = ini.values();
for(Profile.Section section : sectionList){
    String code = section.getName();
    String name = section.get("name");
    String type = section.get("type");
    String id   = section.get("id");

    System.out.format("%-15s%-12s%-25s%s%n", code, type, name, id);
}
```

---

#### Leerlo manualmente

Si aún te interesa analizarlo línea por línea, en vez de generar un patrón diferente para cada clave, conviene generar un patrón genérico para diferenciar secciones de claves, e ir poblando alguna estructura de datos con cada valor leído, sin importar cuál es el nombre de cada clave del INI.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Generamos una clase para ir grabando el valor de cada sección:

```
//clase para 1 sección
class Seccion {
    public String code;
    public Map<String, String> claves = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Seccion(String newCode) {
        code = newCode;
    }
}
```

Estamos usando `code`, que será el nombre de la sección (y la pasamos en el constructor). Y además, estamos un `Map` para almacenar cualquier combinación de clave-valor.

De esta forma, en el código donde leemos el archivo, tenemos un `List` de `Seccion` (la clase que declaramos arriba), y cada elemento de la lista va a tener el nombre de la sección y todas las claves con sus respectivos valores:

```
//list con todas las secciones
List<Seccion> ini = new ArrayList<Seccion>();
Seccion nuevaSeccion = new Seccion("");
```

Y la vamos a ir populando a medida de que leemos el archivo, viendo si coincide con un regex para `[seccion]` o uno para `clave=valor`:

```
//list con todas las secciones
List<Seccion> ini = new ArrayList<Seccion>();
Seccion nuevaSeccion = new Seccion("");

//regex para sección o clave
final Pattern reSeccion = Pattern.compile("^\\h*\\[(.*)\\]");
final Pattern reClave   = Pattern.compile("^\\h*([^=\\s]+)\\h*=\\h*(\\V*)");

//archivo
final String sFile = "ejemplo.ini";
String linea;


//LEER EL ARCHIVO
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(sFile);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    while ((linea = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        //POPULAR LA LISTA (ini)
        //si es una sección (coincide el primer regex)
        Matcher matcher = reSeccion.matcher(linea);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String code = matcher.group(1);   //el nombre de la sección capturado por el grupo 1
            nuevaSeccion = new Seccion(code); //creamos un nuevo objeto para esta sección
            ini.add(nuevaSeccion);            //lo agregamos a la lista
        } else {
            //si es una clave (coincide con el segundo regex)
            matcher = reClave.matcher(linea);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String clave = matcher.group(1);      //el nombre de la clave es el grupo 1
                String valor = matcher.group(2);      //el valor es el grupo 2
                nuevaSeccion.claves.put(clave,valor); //lo agregamos al Map de claves de la sección actual
            }
        }
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Y después podemos imprimir todos los valores:

```
//IMPRMIR TODOS LOS VALORES DE LA LISTA
System.out.format("%-14s%-10s%-31s%s%n", "Codigo", "Categoria", "Nombre", "Id");
for (Seccion seccion : ini) {
    System.out.format(
        "%-14s%-10s%-31s%s%n", 
        seccion.code, 
        seccion.claves.get("type"), 
        seccion.claves.get("name"), 
        seccion.claves.get("id")
    );
}
```

Resultado:

```
Codigo        Categoria Nombre                         Id
018-0001      category  Distritos                      http://datos.madrid.es/egob/kos/actividades/1ciudad21distritos
018-0002      category  Actividades calle, arte urbano http://datos.madrid.es/egob/kos/actividades/ActividadesCalleArteUrbano
018-0003-0006 category  Carreras y maratones           http://datos.madrid.es/egob/kos/actividades/ActividadesDeportivas/CarrerasMaratones
```

Demo: https://www.jdoodle.com/a/p6M

---

#### Respuesta a tu pregunta

> yo leo una linea y tengo que comparar los 4 patrones cada vez que leo una nueva linea para ver que tipo de dato estoy leyendo?

Si bien no te conviene, se pueden unir diferentes expresiones en una, ejemplo:

```
(regex1)|(regex2)|(regex3)|(etc)
```

Y luego ver si coincidió con la primera expresión:

```
if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
```

o con la segunda:

```
} else if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
```

... etc.

Por ejemplo, para tu caso en particular:

```
final String regex    = "^\\h*(?:\\[(\\d{3}(?:-\\d{4}){1,2})\\]|(?:(type)|(name)|(id))\\h*=\\h*(\\V*))$";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

String linea = "name= Actividades calle, arte urbano"; // <-- la línea leída del archivo
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(linea);

String code, type, name, id;
code = type = name = id = "";

if (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        code = matcher.group(1);
    } else if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
        type = matcher.group(5);
    } else if (matcher.group(3) != null) {
        name = matcher.group(5);
    } else if (matcher.group(4) != null) {
        id = matcher.group(5);
    }

    System.out.format("Code: %s - Type: %s - Name: %s - Id: %s", code, type, name, id);
}
```

Pero te recomendaría usar cualquiera de las opciones de arriba antes que esta.